# Where can I find a map of the whole Japan railway system?

Tags: trains, public-transport, japan, maps, japan-rail

I can't seem to find a map that includes every railway in Japan (it's very very difficult, actually). Is there a map (as photo) that includes every single railway, except google map?

Comment: When I was there last year, we referred to [this map](http://en.18dao.net/images/9/93/Map-Japan.jpg) a lot, to identify what connections existed, but given all the local metros and monorails and the like, to fit all the detail for the whole of Japan is very unlikely.

Comment: You could use [openstreetmaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/35.003/136.637&layers=T) and use the transport-layer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here you go: [全国鉄軌道路線図](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%88%A5%E5%86%8A%E3%80%8E%E9%89%84%E9%81%93%E6%89%8B%E5%B8%B3%E3%80%8F-%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E9%89%84%E8%BB%8C%E9%81%93%E8%B7%AF%E7%B7%9A%E5%9B%B3%E3%80%88%E9%95%B7%E5%B0%BA%E7%89%88%E3%80%89%E7%AC%AC%EF%BC%91%E7%89%88-%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A8%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3-%E6%89%80%E6%BE%A4-%E7%A7%80%E6%A8%B9/dp/4422240706)

￥1,296 from Amazon.co.jp.  Here's a [blog review](http://tetsudotecho.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-161.html) with some pictures of the map folded out.

And yes, that's entirely in Japanese, I very much doubt such a thing exists in English.  To get some idea of the effort that would entail, [here's a closeup](http://conciergeandstyle.com/fetes/tokyo-railway-map-english-7111.png) of another incomplete & partial map covering just the Tokyo metro area.

Comment: I'm thinking now if there could exist a more complex metro area around the world! Amazing!

Comment: I had to thank you for your effort - it was a brilliant answer!

Comment: That's epic! :) When I wrote my comment above I was thinking 'well in theory you could build a fold out one to show all the low level detail...but who would do that?'.  Question answered :)

Comment: @Sigur The London rail and tube services map https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/london-rail-and-tube-services-map.pdf is probably the closest. I've never seen a New York map that has LIRR, MetroNorth and NJT as well as the subway, but that would be getting close too.

Comment: @RichardGadsden, maybe because the Japanese char, but I still think that Japanese map is unbelievable. Thanks for the map.

Comment: The third link appears to be corrupted when I tried it just now

Answer (score 8):

Railway tracé by number of tracks: http://www.itoworld.com/map/14?lon=140.62370&lat=38.79141&zoom=5

Railway tracé by clearance, gauge, number of rails: http://www.itoworld.com/map/15?lon=140.62370&lat=38.79141&zoom=5